# Array Index Out of Bounds Exception Merge Sort Procedure Java

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

I was implementing this merge sort procedure but  it's throwing out of bounds exception  and i can't figure why it's doing so I checked all the array parameters are satisfied but its still having the problem.

```
    public class MergeSort 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        {

        int a[]={2,4,5,7,1,2,3,6};

        System.out.println("Unsorted Array");
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
            }
        try{
        MergeSort m=new MergeSort();
        a=m.merge(a, 0, 3, 7);
        }
        catch(Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("\nSorted Array");
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
            }


        }

    int [] merge(int a[],int p,int q,int r)
        {
        //int a[]={2,4,5,7,1,2,3,6};
        int n1=r-p+1;
        int n2=r-q;

        int L[]=new int[n1+1];
        int R[]=new int[n2+1];



        for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
        {
            L[i]=a[i];
        }
        q=q+1;
        for(int i=0;i<n2-1;i++)
        {
            R[i]=a[q+i];
        }

        //L[n1+1]=9;
        ///R[n2+1]=9;

        int i=0,j=0;

        for(int k=0;k<r;k++)
        {
            if(L[i]<=R[j])
            {
                a[k]=L[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                a[k]=R[j];
                j++;
            }
        }




        return a;
        }
    }
```

```
Unsorted Array
2 4 5 7 1 2 3 6 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at scom.id.MergeSort.merge(MergeSort.java:63)
    at scom.id.MergeSort.main(MergeSort.java:20)

Sorted Array
1 2 2 3 0 0 3 6
```

Comment: What is the exact error message, and what line is causing it? Edit question and show us the full stacktrace, and since we can't see line numbers, tell us which line it is.

Comment: It'd help if your formatting was consistent.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Please do not apply *your* personal code style to other peoples questions/answers. OP's code style was to have `{` on separate lines. That is a perfectly valid code style. Undo'ing edit.

Comment: @Andreas the line's are  a=m.merge(a, 0, 3, 7); and  if(L[i]<=R[j])

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson what's wrong with it please elaborate.

Comment: Your brackets are opening and closing at seemingly random indentation levels. It'd be easier to spot any problems if it was formatted well.

Comment: @SiddharthBhardwaj It's *very* uncommon for the braces themselves to be indented, but if that's your style, *stick to it*. E.g. the braces for the class is not like that, some of your `for` loops have them indented but some don't, and your `try` blocks are *entirely* differently indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modifications to your code to make it work. Here you have it:

```
public class MergeSort {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{

     int a[]={2,4,5,7,1,2,3,6};

     System.out.println("Unsorted Array");
     for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
     }
     try{
        MergeSort m=new MergeSort();
        a=m.merge(a, 0, 3, 7);
     }catch(Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     System.out.println("\nSorted Array");
     for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
     }
  }

  int [] merge(int a[],int p,int q,int r){
  //int a[]={2,4,5,7,1,2,3,6};
  int n1=q-p+2;
  int n2=r-q+1;

  int L[]=new int[n1];
  int R[]=new int[n2];

  for(int i=0;i<n1 -1;i++){
    L[i]=a[p+i];
  }
  L[n1 -1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  //q=q+1;
  for(int i=0;i<n2 -1;i++){
    R[i]=a[q+i+1];
  }
  R[n2-1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  //L[n1+1]=9;
  ///R[n2+1]=9;

  int i=0,j=0;

  for(int k = p; k <= r; k++){
      if(L[i] <= R[j]){
        a[k] = L[i++];
    }else{
        a[k] = R[j++];
    }
  }
  return a;
 }
}
```

Comment: 7 is missing from result.

Comment: Could  you pleas explain why we are putting L[n1-1]=Integer.Max_Value ;and R[n2-1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

Comment: It is a reference to know that we've reached the end of the array. The idea is to add an "infinite" value at the end, so when we reach this value, the algorithm will only copy the values of the other array because we guarantee that they are going to be lower.
Another way to achieve this would be to check in each iteration if one of the arrays to merge has reached its last index, and then just copy the other one, but if both arrays have similar sizes, this would imply a lot of unnecesary comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

line 51 needs to be

`for(int k=0;k<r-1;k++)`

that got it to work for me

Comment: Really? Unsorted Array: `2 4 5 7 1 2 3 6`, Sorted Array: `1 2 2 3 0 0 3 6`. Does that *"work for you"*? Because it sure doesn't look like the right output to me.

Comment: @Austin but it has to be sorted as well,is there's something wrong with merge algorithm i am using.

Comment: it's very hard for me to understand your code unless you can tell me what the different variables mean.

Answer (score 0):

I did few changes for merging two left and right arrays in one single array of sorted element.Here is the solution which is running properly.
Hope this will help you understand what is going wrong.

```
public class MergeSort {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

    int a[] = {2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 6};
    System.out.println("Unsorted Array");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    MergeSort m = new MergeSort();
    a = m.merge(a, 0, 3, 7);
    System.out.println("\nSorted Array");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}

int[] merge(int a[], int p, int q, int r) {
    //int a[]={2,4,5,7,1,2,3,6};
    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;

    int L[] = new int[n1];
    int R[] = new int[n2];


    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        L[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        R[i] = a[q + i + 1];
    }

    //L[n1+1]=9;
    ///R[n2+1]=9;

    int i = 0, j = 0 , k = 0;

    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            a[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            a[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < n1) {
        a[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        a[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    return a;
   }
}
```

First thing wrong is array sizes that are allocated for left and right array to hold temporarily.

Comment: your solution is working fine , but what  is wrong with my code is my primary concern.

Comment: So first thing is that

Comment: int n1=r-p+1; is Wrong. It should be n1 = q-p+1; Which represents the size of left array.  k<r is wrong it should be k <= r.Also their should be conditions on i and j as i < n1 and j < n2. So you will not not exceed array size of left and right array.